# Animate objects created from a grid-mesh / plane

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

My Goal is to animate how a plane can be used to create certain objects using the bend / other modifiers

1. Plane to Cylinder

[image: animate 1]

2. Cylinder to Torus (note: had to rotate the Empty for this to work)

[image: animate 2]

3. Torus to Hyperboloid to a Sphere (How can I do this in Blender)
   Not sure how to use the bend / other modifiers to do this.
   Here's an animation of what I'm trying to do.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evlm7.jpg

I've attached the blend file below
[image]

Comment: Hey :). Off-topic, but I just love how the jagged ends line up. Now, that's attention to detail :).

Comment: Thanks but I can't take credit for that adapted a tutorial to fit my needs ;-)  https://youtu.be/udiL9VllksQ?t=111

Comment: Not exactly the same, but is it what you want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAYvk.gif

Comment: @lemon Yes :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is to use two *"simple deform"* modifiers:

- one animated from a circle, bent -360°, (for the torus) to a half circle, bent 180°, for the sphere
- the second to bend around the previous by 360° to give it the volume (torus or sphere)

The base grid is parallel to front view and centered to avoid the usage of empties in the bend modifiers.

[image]

Though, we also want here to join correctly the uneven grid borders (top to bottom and left to right):

[image]

which means we have to bend more than 360° to join them. And doing so, the mesh won't be a perfect sphere at the end.

So we need to compensate that. This is done with a *"cast (to sphere) modifier"* centered on an empty placed at the center of the sphere. This modifier is also animated so that its influence is null when the shape is a torus.

That gives us this setting:

[image]

- Simple deform around X animated from -380° (*) to 180°
- Simple deform around Z at 369° (*)
- Cast (to sphere) modifier animated from 0 to 0.5
- Weld to get ride of duplicate vertices
- Wireframe

(* these values are tuned to that border overlap correctly and weld modifier works on them)

[image]