# Calculating the correct angle needed to bend a plane into a "cylinder shape"

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mathematics

Calculating the correct angle needed to bend a plane into a "cylinder shape".

I have a 5x5 diamond plane that when I bend it **396** degrees it becomes a "cylinder shape"
[image: 5x5]

Another diamond grid 15x15 requires **372** degrees for it to close.

[image: bend2]
**How can I calculate the angle (using a formula) I would need to bend other diamond planes into a "cylinder shape"**

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199064/animate-objects-created-from-a-grid-mesh-plane/199072#199072

Comment: @lemon yes it is similar but I noticed if I change the diamond shapes the angle required is different I'll post a animation and add it to the question.

Comment: yes... just noticed this was your question...  : )

Comment: Either it is a linear relationship and you can use [linear regression](https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/linear1/) by mapping the difference in shape (only one parameter must vary) and the resulting angle. Or it's another thing and you would need good old mathematics. Could you elaborate on what parameter changed between your 2 tests ?

Comment: @Gorgious The only thing changed was the diamond grid size the first was 5x5 and the second was 15x15

Comment: According to linear regression the formula is angle = -2.4*(number of rows) + 408 °. Can you test it out with another number of rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just linear, it seems

[image]

If it is for N diamonds in the line above, then the angle is:

```
360 * (1 + 1 / (2 * N))
```

as we need to fill one half one diamond plus these N.

Or to say it another way, this is the ratio of the size considering the half diamond by the size without it x the angle.